# Entity reference field to show translation of nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, translation

In Drupal I have a content type "Genetic Test" which has an entity reference field (select list) where I can select nodes of the content type "Material".
The Material nodes all have English set as their source language, but they are also translated in Dutch and French (entity translation).

The problem I'm having is, when I edit a node of the type "Genetic Test" with the interface language set to English, the select list shows the Material nodes, but when I change the interface language to Dutch or French the list is empty.

So my question is, how do I get the select list to show the Dutch or French node titles of the content type Material when I'm editing the Genetic Test node in said languages?

I hope I made myself clear a bit, English isn't my first language.

Thank you in advance for any help.

BTW: I'm working in Drupal 7.

Comment: Are you sure that your entities have translations available? It might make sense that they arent included in the list (especially if you are using a view to filter them)